# Run app on iOS device in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, monogame, visual-studio-mac

I have problem with running my iOS app (Monogame) on my physical iPhone X device in Visual Studio for Mac (former Xamarin Studio).

I can test it in emulator, but I don't see option for physical device in list of devices. If I try to create an app in Xcode there is that option.

I have connected my iPhone X to MacBook Pro 2017 via Lightning cable.

Do you have some ideas where can be problem?

There is my info.plist:

[image]

Comment: Does your phone show up in "Devices and Simulators" (Cmd-Shift-2)? When you first connected the phone, did you answer "yes" to the "trust this computer" question?

Comment: Yes I answer yes on trust this computer. Where can I find Devices and Simulators because that shortcut Cmd-Shift-2 doesn't work for me.